# Django: Query by pk of all models

Tags: python, django, inheritance, model

I need to query across multiple tables by primary_keys, which are unique (uuids).

My idea was to use model inheritance for querying all models at once. I've got a BaseItem and all other models are subclasses of this BaseItem model.

Now, my query does not return what I expected and needed. Here's a sample model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class BaseRev(models.Model):
    rev_id = models.CharField(max_length=32, primary_key=True)
    item_id = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField()


class NamedRev(BaseRev):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile', related_name='namedrev_creator', blank=True, null=True)
```

When I create a NamedRev with pk = "1234" and make a query like

```
BaseRev.objects.get(pk="1234")
```

I get a result with the correct pk, but it's of type BaseItem. According to the docs that's the correct behaviour, as the the rev_id field does only exist in the BaseRev table and the addional fields for the NamedRev in the NamedRev table.

How do I get "proper" and complete (with all fields) objects of type NamedRev for the given query?

Cheers,

Jan

Answer (score 0):

What if you set your parent class to be abstract:

```
class BaseRev(models.Model):
    rev_id = models.CharField(max_length=32, primary_key=True)
    item_id = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Comment: This gives me an attribute error (renamed BaseRev to ABaseRev) AttributeError: type object 'ABaseRev' has no attribute 'objects'

Answer (score 0):

After you have fetched your BaseRev, do:

```
>>> base_rev = BaseRev.objects.get(pk="1234")
>>> base_rev.namedrev
<NamedRev: NamedRev object>
```

Assign the above to another variable and you should be able to access NamedRev's fields.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve, you can query on NamedRev: `NamedRev.objects.get(pk="1234")`

Comment: My goal is: I have an id (unique primary key) and don't know the type of the corrsponding item / table. So, I could manually loop over all tables / models until I find a matching object. Or -- that was my idea -- query the base table hoping that the Django ORM queries the derived tables and returns an object of the inherited type. But Django doesn't create columns for the inherited fields in the inherited models, so it basically queries only the base table. Looks like it's the easiest to loop over all tables manually ...

Answer (score 0):

you could insert "type" field in your base model, so you can query the base model and then ask for it's type. override `save()` method of each model to set the type before saving.